# Magic number in RTP over TCP

Tags: tcp, h.264, rtsp, rtp

According to [RTSP - RTP over TCP](http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2011/03/rtsp-rtp-over-tcp.html)

```
RTP Data

After the setup, RTP data will be sent through the TCP socket that is used for RTSP commands. The RTP data will be encapsulate in the following format

| magic number | channel number | embedded data length | data |

magic number - 1 byte value of hex 0x24
channel number - 1 byte value to denote the channel
embedded data length - 2 bytes to denote the embedded data length
data - data packet, ie RTP packet, with the total length of the embedded data length
```

Is that mean that the magic number (0x24) can't preset in rtp/h264 data ?

when I see 0x24 I know that it start of rtp packet?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that mean that the magic number (0x24) can't preset in rtp/h264 data ?

Since the actual payload is prefixed with its length it is clear where the payload starts and ends. It will not search for the magic number inside the payload, length or channel number but only at the position where the magic number should be.

> when I see 0x24 I know that it start of rtp packet?

No. As explained the 0x24 can be anywhere in the data, not only where the magic number is.

Comment: @parser1234: There isn't actually a "magic". This is about as magic as an RTSP command is magic. The `$` (i.e. 0x24) signals that the next part will be embedded RTP and not an RTSP command.

Comment: Why I didn't find the `0x24` magic in rtsp rfc? ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326 )

Comment: @parser1234: [RFC 2326 section 10.12](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326#section-10.12): *"... Stream data such as RTP packets is encapsulated by an ASCII dollar
   sign (24 hexadecimal), ..."*.